# Asynchrnous Large File Upload with Jersey Rest Client

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey

I have the following code that does fileupload. It works but I need to make the upload asynchronous with user not waiting for the upload to finish.

```
@Path("/files")
public class JerseyFileUpload {

private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://uploadedtest/";

/**
 * Upload a File
 */

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(FormDataMultiPart form) {

     FormDataBodyPart filePart = form.getField("file");

     ContentDisposition headerOfFilePart = filePart.getContentDisposition();
     System.out.println("============================================");
     System.out.println("Header is: " + headerOfFilePart.getFileName());
     System.out.println("============================================");

     InputStream fileInputStream =  filePart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
     String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER+headerOfFilePart.getFileName();
    // save the file to the server
    saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

    String output = "File saved to server location using: " + filePath;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();

        uploadedInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

My Html file is like this

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Form Page</title>
    </head>
     <body>
     <h1>Select a file to upload</h1>

  <form action="rest/files/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
   </p>

   <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
</form>

   </body>
    </html>
```

My requirement is to make it asynchronous and run it as OCTECTSTREAM instead of Multipart as my files are going to be bigger mostly like 5gb plus. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You need to learn some Javascript/jQuery and make an AJAX request.

Comment: @peeskillet with Ajax will it handled at server side or client side?